# Map not displaying on Safari

Tags: google-maps, safari

I'm initialising the map like this:

```
function initialize() {
   var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
   var map_options = {
     scrollwheel: false,
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.4611388, -2.9719832),
     zoom: 17,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
     originalCenter: new google.maps.LatLng(56.4611388, -2.9719832)
}
map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
```

The map appears fine on every browser (including Safari Mobile) except Safari (mine is 7.0.3) on OS X. You can check out my page [here](http://albarakadundee.co.uk/).

I did some searching and found similar issues with Safari and Google Maps but to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried the [release version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) (v=3) rather than the experimental version?  (not sure if that will help).  Are you getting any javascript errors in Safari?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the safari specific code on your page.  Browser detection can be problematic.

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks for trying to help! No the safari code doesn't affect it, I get the same thing without. I'm going to check the release version and will get back to you!

Comment: @geocodezip I think when loading from `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js` it's automatically using latest version, from what I can tell. So nah still nothing...

Comment: As described in the [link in my first comment on "Versioning"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning), that loads the "experimental version" v3.exp (currently 3.17), I would suggest trying the release version (v=3, currently 3.16) and the frozen version (v=3.0, currently 3.15); might not fix it. I don't have Safari available right now.

Comment: @geocodezip Thank you very much for your help! My bad should've read that first!